# Type 'AbstractControl<any, any>' is missing the properties from type 'FormControl<any>': defaultValue, registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange

Tags: angular

I'm following the contents of the Ng-book, while trying out the code for reactive forms, I'm getting the error:
 "TS2739: Type 'AbstractControl<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl': defaultValue, registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange".
Below are the codes for my html and type script files.

**demo-form-sku-with-builder.component.html**

```
<div id="demo-form-sku">
  <div>
    <h2 id="sku-heading"> Demo Form: Sku </h2>
    <form [formGroup]="myForm"
          (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)"
          class="ui form">
      <div class="field">
        <label for="skuInput">SKU</label>
        &nbsp;
        <input type="text"
               id="skuInput"
               placeholder="SKU"
               [formControl]="myForm.controls['sku']">
      </div>
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="ui button">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**demo-form-with-builder.components.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo-form-sku-with-builder',
  templateUrl: './demo-form-sku-with-builder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo-form-sku-with-builder.component.css']
})
export class DemoFormSkuWithBuilderComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({ 
      'sku': ['ABC123']
    }); 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  onSubmit(value: string): void {
    console.log('you submitted value: ', value);
  }
}
```

I'm not able to understand what is causing this error other than that "formControl is inherited from AbstractControl class and the compiler is unable to do type conversion from object of AbsractControl to formControl. I went through a few SO articles and none of them seem to address this exact issue. What is happening here, and how it can be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you're seeing is related to TypeScript type checking, maybe are you using angular in strict templates mode. One solution could be to put strict checking on false, but I don't encourage that, so you have two options:

1. Use "formcontrolname", since you are already in context of a group:
   https://stackblitz.com/edit/formcontrol-add-string-xxtum5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
2. You could create helper function which is doing the casting:

```js
getRate(): FormControl {
    return this.paymentForm.get('rate') as FormControl;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" [formControl]="getRate()">
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you. I went with option 2 and it worked. I'm no longer facing the error.